# What happens when float pointer is typecasted to char pointer?

Tags: c, casting

```
int main()
{
    float f = 12.2;
    char *p1;
    p1 = (char *)&f;
    printf ("%d", *p1);
}
```

This outputs 51.

Comment: No, I did not. Read his original source, and you see that it did have the pointers in the right places. However, the pointer in the cast and the pointer in the printf where then considered as emphasis - which is clearly not what srie raam intended.

Comment: Then look at IEEE 754 representation of 12.2. You will see that is won't support your theory

Comment: `main` returns an `int`.

Answer (score 17):

You can *cast* a `float*` to a `char*` just fine, it's the *using* of such a beast that may be problematic.

When you de-reference it, you'll simply get the `char` representation of the first part (but see below to understand what this really means, it's not as clear as you may think) of the float.

If you're talking about IEE754 floats, 12.2 in IEEE754 float is (abcd are the octets):

```
S EEEEEEEE MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM (sign, exponent, mantissa).
0 10000010 10000110011001100110011
a aaaaaaab bbbbbbbccccccccdddddddd
```

The `00110011` at the end is the 51 (0x33) that you're seeing. The reason you're seeing the *last* bit of the float is because it's stored like this in memory (in a little-endian architecture):

```
00110011 00110011 01000011 01000001
dddddddd cccccccc bbbbbbbb aaaaaaaa
```

which means that the `char*` cast of the `float*` will point at the `dddddddd` part.

On big-endian architectures, you would get the `aaaaaaaa` bit, `01000001`, or 65 (0x41).

Answer (score 1):

1. You cast to (char) instead of (char*).
2. You print it out as integer.
3. Thus you get the least significant byte of f's address.

EDIT: According to the new markup you really truncate the float representation to its least significant byte (on little-endian machines)

Answer (score 1):

Mostly what EFraim says, except that you did cast to char*, only the stackoverflow markup was wrong.

So you get the least significant byte of f's internal representation (in IEEE-754).

Comment: No, he did not. Otherwise he would not get 51. The mantissa is unlikely to be 0.

Comment: With the code as it stands right now, I also get 51 on an x86 machine. 12.2 is (in hex) 33 33 43 41.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the other issues mentioned are fixed, you are getting the integer version of whatever the bit pattern happens to be for that float. Floats have a fairly complicated encoding, so it will be nothing obviously related to the number you put in the float.

Comment: If nothing else, you'll be able to print out the individual bytes to see how complicated the encoding actually is :-)

Answer (score 1):

The question is:

> what happens when float is typecasted to char pointer

The precise answer is:

> Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There is slight deviation to your question I am off the topic,I usually use in such cases the snpritf [Example:](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/)to fisrt format and then you can play the formatted buffer.